# Show MySQL values in specific order

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

So I have the following piece of code.

```
$sql = "SELECT TitreEvent, DescriptionEvent, MomentEvent, image_small, Confidentialite, ID, Creation, Username 
FROM events_home 
WHERE ID = '" . $dnn['IDcontact'] . "' 
ORDER BY Creation DESC";
```

My problem is that I want to display the most recent events first (regardless of who the user is). But now, the events are displayed according to users (IDcontact), and new events are placed at the beginning of the portion of the user.

So if a user is like the second one in the table, the new events he will add will be displayed after the events of the first user. But I want to see the newest events at the top of the list, and I have no idea how.

**EDIT** So there is the missing part. I have tried to put SORT BY RAND () in the first query, but it dosen't change anyting. It just place the first user at the second place, and the second one in the first place.

```
<?php
     $dn = mysql_query("SELECT IDcontact FROM contacts WHERE ID = '".$_SESSION['id']."'");
     if(mysql_num_rows($dn)>0) 
     {
       while ($dnn = mysql_fetch_array($dn)) {
      $req = mysql_query("select TitreEvent, DescriptionEvent, MomentEvent, image_small, Confidentialite, ID, Creation, Username from events_home where ID = '".$dnn['IDcontact']."' ORDER BY Creation DESC");

      if(mysql_num_rows($req)>0) 
            {
             while($dnn = mysql_fetch_array($req)) {
           ?>
```

Comment: **No** idea? Read up on the `WHERE` clause and the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Are you talking to look in my query, cause I have a mistake??? Or you are saying that I can't put WHERE and ORDER BY in the same query?

Comment: The query you have included only shows the results for a single user id. If you are trying to retrieve results for multiple users, please show us the complete code.

Comment: @freddy I'm saying that this is a trivial problem and that if you took the trouble to understand what these clauses do you'd have a solution very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're running this in a loop from a previous query result. In which case you need to change the 'parent' query. If there's no such thing then why are you sorting results by the user's ID and expecting all results regardless of the user?

**EDIT**:

You should never run queries in loops.

```
<?php
$dn = mysql_query("
SELECT e.TitreEvent, e.DescriptionEvent, e.MomentEvent, e.image_small, e.Confidentialite, e.ID, e.Creation, e.Username,c.IDcontact 
FROM events_home e LEFT JOIN contacts c ON c.ID = e.ID 
ORDER BY e.Creation DESC
LIMIT 0,30"); // Just in case
```

Here's your query, hope that helps.

Comment: This is a comment, especially the part about your question *"why are you sorting results by the user's ID and expecting all results regardless of the user?"*

Comment: I'm not much of the rhetorical type myself. I usually ask questions in comments, then I present an actual answer to solve an OP's problem upon presentation of fully tested code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- As you see there's code that the OP hadn't shown. How do you suppose I would have answered with an actual piece of code? It's cool I don't do this for votes. Stick around for the edit, see if that pleases you.

Comment: I only have a problem: there is duplicates of all the events...

Comment: @freddy Well you only run this once. This will give you all the last events joined with your contacts table. I think you'll get a better understanding if you execute this in mySQL and see the result. This join is basically pointless because you already have the `ID` you're joining the tables on. I just did that to show you how it is actually done when you want to get results from more than one table at the same tame. Having queries in loops is really not something you want to have in your scripts.

Comment: Well I think you forget the WHERE ID = '".$_SESSION['id']."' part. Thats maby why it send events twice? But I don't really know where to put it in the code you give me...

Comment: Sorting by id will only give you results by the given ID. In the question you say that you want to display __all__ latest events.

Comment: For the selected users only... to help you, in my original first query, I select the friend (IDcontact) of the logged user(session_id), and in the second query, I select the events of the  friends.

Comment: __My problem is that I want to display the most recent events first (regardless of who the user is).__ You need to make up your mind.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said regardless of who the IDcontact is... my bad. But I found the mistake... it's in the c.ID = e.ID, it should be c.IDcontact = e.ID! And thanks for the good answer, it really help me.

Comment: @freddy Well it was not that easy to figure your database relations out, all I did was take a guess, when you're not specifying any database table structure then you're gonna have to figure out the rest yourself, as you have. I'm happy I helped, good luck! `^.^`

Comment: That's always what happens when an OP doesn't post full code or doesn't give full details of the problem at hand. Giving tested code or giving actual steps for the OP to fix the code her/himself are usually the best ways to find a solution. They always post it "after the fact". @php_nub_qq